# asp.net menu skiplink

Tags: asp.net, menu, indentation

The ASP.NET menu creates a skiplink which has 0x19 size and it is invisible in Explorer, but it is rendered in Chrome! So my menu has an extra 19 pixels indent! How do I overcome this? Here is its HTML:

```
<a href="#HeaderMenu1_Menu1_SkipLink">
<img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=ChOum_wTGSzbwK97BQPV0ITybaR8NYj0fCEsJDNZ46Dhv_eO5a-qipjyNL4I6aiynUitzcOuIwIjwyFX_snxVbyAZO7glY1Vhbd4zETG4j41&amp;t=634280594527374621" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add `SkipLinkText=""` to `<asp:Menu>` tag and this code won't be rendered.

Comment: Thanks A million. I was Scratching my head for two days and couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used the built in Menu control so did some digging and found that the default asp.net template it wraps the `asp:Menu` control in a div with the following styles:

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:Menu...
```

The styles are defined as:

```
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. It even works if `.hideSkiplink` class is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set SkipLink = String.Empty